# Sharing @input between angular components

Tags: angular

It is possible to share data between 2 angular components while one of them is used inside the other component?
I am using the following code to define the templates for the components and i would like to specify the "Source" property only once.

Is it possible to inherit the import from a parent component? 
As i will only ever use the "ui-grid-header" inside the "ui-grid"

For this project i am Angular version 5.2

And since i am fairly new to Angular development.
Is there a place where i would be able to find information like this?

---

**Template**

```
<ui-grid [source]="gridDatasource">
  <ng-template #headerTemplate let-data>
    <th>
        <ui-grid-header [source]="datasource" [sortColumn]="'Name'">
            Name
        </ui-grid-header>
    </th>
    <!-- Omitted rest of the code for example -->
  </ng-template>
</ui-grid>
```

---

**ui-grid-component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ui-grid',
    templateUrl: './grid.component.html'
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit{
    @ContentChild('headerTemplate')
    headerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    @Input("source")
    public datasource: AbstractGridDataSource;

    /* Omitted rest of the code for example */
}
```

---

**ui-grid-header-component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ui-grid-header',
    template:
`
<ng-container *ngIf="datasource">
    <a [ngClass]={disabled:!sortColumn} (click)="sortColumn && datasource.setOrderColumn(sortColumn)" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </a>
</ng-container>
`
})
export class GridHeaderComponent {
    @Input("source")
    public datasource: AbstractGridDataSource;

    @Input("sortColumn")
    public sortColumn: string;
}
```

Comment: you should see [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But i recommend you to supply more information while asking angular questions. For example grid.component.html is important for your question. It's best to prepare a stackblitz fork on https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular with minimal reproduction. So community will be able to give you the meaningful answers much more easily.

Comment: And also reviewing code at https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/tree/master/src/components would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is solved using shared service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ui-grid',
    templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
    providers: [SharedService]
})
constructor GridComponent(private service:SharedService)
//save input i.e. sharedService.set(input)
//------------------------------------------------
constructor GridHeaderComponent(private service:SharedService)
//get input i.e. sharedService.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is propagate the `source` from your `ui-grid-header` component into all `ui-grid-header` sub-components, like so:

In your `GridComponent` get a hold of of the child components:

`@ContentChildren(GridHeaderComponent) headers: QueryList<GridHeaderComponent>;`

For a simple one-time binding, simply use `ngAfterContentInit` to pass the value:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.headers.forEach(header => header.source = this.source);
}
```

If you need to handle many-times-binding, you'll need to use `ngOnChanges` to detect whenever `source` changes and propagate that down there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I have implemented the code are provided by you but in the ngAfterContentInit function by this.headers is an empty array.

Comment: This will not work, as he projected the GridHeaderComponent as a templateRef, removing the ng-template wrapping the grid header component may solve the issue!